# Clonar objetos de classe usando ICloneable

Tags: c#

Estou tentando usar a **Interface** ICloneable para copiar um objeto, mas estou tendo um problema quando ele tem como propriedade uma classe pois o *ICloneable* não cria um novo endereço de memória para esses objetos, mas fica apontando para o endereço de memória original da cópia.

```
public class Pessoa : ICloneable
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public Pessoa(string nome, int idade, Endereco endereco)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Idade = idade;
        Endereco = endereco;
    }

    public string Info()
    {
        return String.Concat(this.Nome, ", ", this.Idade, " anos, Endereço: ", Endereco.Rua, " - ", Endereco.Cidade, ", CEP: ", Endereco.Cep);
    }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    public Endereco(string rua, string cidade, string cep)
    {
        Rua = rua;
        Cidade = cidade;
        Cep = cep;
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Pessoa Joao = new Pessoa("João", 19, new Endereco("Rua Augusta", "São Paulo", "123456789"));
    Pessoa Pedro = (Pessoa)Joao.Clone(); // Clona os valores dos atributos
    Pedro.Nome = "Pedro";

    Console.WriteLine(Joao.Info());
    Console.WriteLine(Pedro.Info());
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Alterando a cidade do Pedro...
    Pedro.Endereco.Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro";

    Console.WriteLine(Joao.Info()); // Alterou a cidade do João também
    Console.WriteLine(Pedro.Info());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Na lógica de `Clone`, voce precisa clonar nos endereços que existem dentro do objeto Pessoa. Desta forma os endereços também precisam ser `IClonable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meu caro, infelizmente o .Net não conta com o recurso de clonar um objeto de forma controlada. A única forma padrão dada pelo .Net é o próprio método `MemberwiseClone`, que faz o que se chama de clonagem não profunda.

A forma de clonar também objetos internos, requer intervenção da sua parte, assim:

```
public object Clone()
{
    var clone = (Pessoa)this.MemberwiseClone();
    clone.Endereco = (Endereco)clone.Endereco.Clone();
    return clone;
}
```

**Alternativa: Serializar/Desserializar**

Outra alternativa seria serializar e depois desserializar o objeto, mas isso pode ter vários inconvenientes, caso na estrutura de objetos existam objetos não serializáveis.

Exemplo:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
    return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

**Alternativa: Reflexão**

Existe uma alternativa que dá mais trabalho, e no caso seria usar reflexão para montar o método de clonagem. Neste caso, você teria de avaliar se isso vale a pena.

Eu utilizo a seguinte solução para fazer clonagem profunda de um objeto,
usando reflexão para poder construir os métodos de clonagem de forma que
fique com boa performance:

```
public static class CloneHelper
{
    public static T Clone<T>(T objToClone) where T : class
    {
        return CloneHelper<T>.Clone(objToClone);
    }
}

public static class CloneHelper<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly Lazy<PropertyHelper.Accessor<T>[]> _LazyCloneableAccessors =
        new Lazy<PropertyHelper.Accessor<T>[]>(CloneableProperties, isThreadSafe: true);

    private static readonly Func<object, object> MemberwiseCloneFunc;

    static CloneHelper()
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        MemberwiseCloneFunc = (Func<object, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<object, object>),
            typeof(T).GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", flags));
    }

    [ReflectionPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    private static PropertyHelper.Accessor<T>[] CloneableProperties()
    {
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance
                           | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
                           | BindingFlags.Public
                           | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        var result = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(bindingFlags)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && !p.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetMethods(bindingFlags).Any(x => x.Name == "Clone"))
            .Select(PropertyHelper.CreateAccessor<T>)
            .Where(a => a != null)
            .ToArray();

        return result;
    }

    public static T Clone(T objToClone)
    {
        var clone = MemberwiseCloneFunc(objToClone) as T;

        // clonando todas as propriedades que possuem um método Clone
        foreach (var accessor in _LazyCloneableAccessors.Value)
        {
            var propToClone = accessor.GetValueObj(objToClone);
            var clonedProp = propToClone == null ? null : ((dynamic)propToClone).Clone() as object;
            accessor.SetValueObj(objToClone, clonedProp);
        }

        return clone;
    }

}

public static class PropertyHelper
{
    // solução baseada em: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085798/creating-an-performant-open-delegate-for-an-property-setter-or-getter

    public abstract class Accessor<T>
    {
        public abstract void SetValueObj(T obj, object value);
        public abstract object GetValueObj(T obj);
    }

    public class Accessor<TTarget, TValue> : Accessor<TTarget>
    {
        private readonly PropertyInfo _property;
        public Accessor(PropertyInfo property)
        {
            _property = property;

            if (property.GetSetMethod(true) != null)
                this.Setter = (Action<TTarget, TValue>)
                    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TTarget, TValue>), property..GetSetMethod(true));

            if (property.GetGetMethod(true) != null)
                this.Getter = (Func<TTarget, TValue>)
                Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TTarget, TValue>), property.GetGetMethod(true));
        }

        public Action<TTarget, TValue> Setter { get; private set; }
        public Func<TTarget, TValue> Getter { get; private set; }

        public override void SetValueObj(TTarget obj, object value) { Setter(obj, (TValue)value); }
        public override object GetValueObj(TTarget obj) { return Getter(obj); }
        public override string ToString() { return _property.ToString(); }
    }

    public static Accessor<T> CreateAccessor<T>(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod();
        if (getMethod == null || getMethod.GetParameters().Length != 0)
            return null;
        var accessor = (Accessor<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(Accessor<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T),
                property.PropertyType), property);
        return accessor;
    }

    public static Accessor<TIn, TOut> CreateAccessor<TIn, TOut>(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return (Accessor<TIn, TOut>)CreateAccessor<TIn>(property);
    }
}
```

Forma de utilizar:

```
public object Clone()
{
    return CloneHelper.Clone(this);
}
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar o método usando reflection mas ele encontra um erro falando que o Reflection.PropertyInfo não tem o a definição do *SetMethod* nem do *GetMethod*

Comment: Arrumei o erro... estava recuperando o método de Get ao invés do Set para verificar a quantidade de parâmetros, e ai testei o número de parâmetros com `!= 1`, mas deveria ser `!= 0`.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas ainda está dando o mesmo erro, será que fiz algo errado? Uso o VS2010

Comment: O erro que está acontecendo é na hora de compilar, ou quando já está rodando?

Comment: Compilar: http://i.imgur.com/1FpuJdE.png

Comment: É a versão do .Net. Qual versão você está usando?

Comment: Fiz um ajuste... pode verificar se agora funciona?

Comment: Agora compilou, a método usando Reflection eu preciso por nos objetos da classe também? Pois ele copiou corretamente os dados só que os objetos de classes continuam referenciando pro primeiro. Obrigado e desculpe pelo delay na resposta.  Versão .NET: 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Comment: Essa implementação que eu fiz, só vai clonar as propriedades que também tiverem um método `Clone`, por exemplo, se a classe `A` tem uma propriedade da classe `B`, então `A` e `B` devem possuir um método `Clone`... mas se isso não te atender, posso te indicar um outro caminho.

Comment: Miguel não precisa, realmente muito legal a forma que você fez, me desculpe estou aprendendo por isso tive essa dificuldade de entender, mas vou estudar seu código!

Comment: Disponha... estamos todos aprendendo! =D

Comment: @MiguelAngelo o que significa a barra vertical única na linha `var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic;`?

Comment: Isso é um operador bitwise, que mescla os bits dos operandos. Exemplo: se `A` em binário for `1001`, e `B` em binário for `0010`, e eu fizer `C = A | B`, o valor de C em binário será `1011`.

Answer (score 3):

O conceito de clonagem de objetos pode ter duas implementações:

1. *Shallow* (rasa): Clona o objeto mas copia apenas as referências para os objetos que referencia, exceção feita para os tipos por valor (*value types*) cujo valor é, por definição, sempre copiado.
2. *Deep** (profunda): Clona o objeto e todos os objetos por ele referenciados.

Como a clonagem depende da implementação pode acontecer que a clonagem seja mista. Ou seja, alguns objetos internos ao serem clonados para obter uma clonagem profunda podem realizar apenas uma clonagem rasa.

Quando se controla a definição das classes, há quem prefira definir a sua própria definição de `ICloneable` em que o método `Clone` recebe um parâmetro indicando se a clonagem é rasa ou profunda:

```
public interface ICloneable
{
    object Clone(bool deep);
}

public interface ICloneable<T> : ICloneable
{
    T Clone(bool deep);
}
```

Mas no final, cada um vai ter de implementar a sua clonagem.

Answer (score 1):

Endereço também precisa implementar o IClonable.

```
public class Endereco : ICloneable
    {
        public string Rua { get; set; }
        public string Cidade { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }

        public Endereco(string rua, string cidade, string cep)
        {
            Rua = rua;
            Cidade = cidade;
            Cep = cep;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Daí você altera o Clone de pessoa para que fique dessa forma:

```
public object Clone()
        {
            Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa)this.MemberwiseClone();
            pessoa.Endereco = (Endereco)this.Endereco.Clone();
            return pessoa;
        }
```