# Criar objetos sem referência C#

Tags: c#, referência

Minha dúvida é,  tenho duas instância da classe Pais, pais1 e pais2, criei a 3 instância da classe Pais chamada pais3 e disse que ela será igual a instância pais2, até tudo ok.

Só que meu problema está sendo que quando eu mudo o nome do objeto pais 2, é mudado também no objeto pais3, o que posso fazer não um objeto não ficar referente ao outro?

```
public class Teste
{
    public Teste()
    {
        Pais pais1 = new Pais();
        pais1.Nome = "Pais 1";

        Pais pais2 = new Pais();
        pais2.Nome = "Pais 2";

        Pais pais3 = new Pais();
        pais3 = pais2;

        pais2.Nome = "Pais 1000";
    }        
}
```

Comment: Acho que você procura copiar o objeto de `pais2` (por exemplo, criar um novo objeto e copiar o valor dos membros). Se C# for igual à C++, então isso é muito fácil... basta apenas fazer isso, eu acho: `{ Pais pais3_v = pais2; Pais& pais3 = pais_v; }` (obviamente precisaria atualizar os membros que referenciam/apontam valores)

Comment: @Matheus, sinceramente não compreendi o que você disse.

Comment: Hummm, por exemplo: `Pais pais3 = new Pais(); pais3.Nome = pais2.Nome;`. Deve já haver alguma função para isso no C#.

Comment: @Matheus C# não é igual ao C++. Veja minha resposta.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12048/clonar-objetos-de-classe-usando-icloneable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicação rápida a respeito do seu código:

```
Pais pais3 = new Pais(); // Cria uma nova instância de pais(), 
                         //    e a referencia como pais3.

pais3 = pais2;           // pais3 recebe uma nova referência, e agora
                         //    aponta para o mesmo objeto que pais2;
                         //    o objeto criado na expressão anterior
                         //    não tem mais referências, será coletado
                         //    pelo Garbage Collector eventualmente
                         //    e descartado.
```

Assim, para todos os fins práticos tanto `pais3` quanto `pais2` estão efetivamente apontando para o mesmo ponto da memória.

O que você está querendo pode ser melhor exposto desta forma:

> Um objeto cujas propriedades possuam o mesmo valor de um outro objeto.

Uma das possibilidade é a clonagem, que se divide entre cópias rasas (*shallow copy*) e profundas (*deep copy*). A diferença é que a primeira mantém referências para os mesmos objetos apontados pelas propriedades do objeto clonado; a segunda tenta também clonar os objetos referenciados.

O exemplo a seguir demonstra a criação de uma cópia rasa:

```
Pais pais3 = (Pais)pais2.MemberwiseClone();
```

O exemplo abaixo utiliza `MemoryStream` e `BinaryFormatter` para permitir cópias profundas:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    // Deep clone
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T a)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return (T) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Utilização:

```
Pais pais3 = pais2.DeepClone();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213649/1845714

Comment: poderia me explicar qual a diferença da cópia raza para a cópia profunda?

Comment: @NicolaBogar Ele já explica na resposta. É tipo, se você tem `pais2.ref` e `pais2.ref` referencia à um objeto, então `pais3.ref` vai receber um novo objeto igual à `pais2.ref` (o mesmo ocorre recursivamente nos membros).

Answer (score 6):

[Leia isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Em tipos por referência o operador de atribuição apenas copia a referência da variável, na prática você não tem dois objetos e sim duas variáveis que apontam para o mesmo objeto. Então se mexer no objeto através de uma variáveis, a outra variável enxerga a alteração porque é o mesmo objeto, você não criou outro novo.

A solução pra isso é criar um novo objeto do zero, já que parece que deseja que cada um seja individual, tenha sua própria identidade.

Uma forma fácil é criar o objeto na mão como criou os outros objetos, eventualmente até usando o anterior como base pra pegar os valores já usados, mas ainda criando um novo objeto.

Se vai fazer isso com frequência compensa criar um construtor que receba um objeto `Pais` como argumento e o próprio construtor se encarregue de ler os dados deste objeto para criar um novo objeto. Nem sempre isto é possível.

Pode usar uma técnica de clonagem dentro do objeto. Nem sempre é fácil fazer funcionar corretamente. Leia uma [pergunta sobre clone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177137/101).

[Também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156883/101). [Um outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171840/101).

A [clonagem por serialização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185452/101) pode ser solução em alguns casos.

Uma outra solução é fazer o [`Pais` ser um tipo por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101), aí não tem esse problema. Mas nem sempre é adequado. A mudança na semântica pode inviabilizar certos usos. Pelo texto mostrando o que deseja parece que não pode fazer isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: eu criei um método conforme ele explicou usando a MemoryStream e o BinaryFormatter e deu certo, mas a minha dúvida é a seguinte, qual a diferença de eu fazer essa clonagem por esse metódo ou usando o MemberwiseClone. Não consegui compreender essa explicação. **(A diferença é que a primeira mantém referências para os mesmos objetos apontados pelas propriedades do objeto clonado; a segunda tenta também clonar os objetos referenciados.)**

Comment: @NicolaBogar dar certo e estar certo são coisas diferentes. Depois eu vou melhorar a resposta, mas eu não sei se faria isto. Leu os *links* que eu passei? Tem esse tb: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138003/101, depois eu posto algo sobre isso

Comment: eu li os artigos sim, e realmente deu certo, era exatamente o que precisava, clonar o objeto sem ter nenhuma referência. Só  fiquei na dúvida de quando usar a serialização ou pelo modo do MemberwiseClone, apenas isso, mas obrigado pelas informações. Deu para resolver meu problema em questão que é obter uma cópia do objeto sem ser por referência.

Comment: Interessante a solução de fazer `Pais` um Struct.

Comment: vou repetir, dar certo e estar certo são coisas completamente diferentes. @Matheus mas neste caso não parece ser adequado, pelo menos em objeto real. Claro que pode ser que sim, se apenas tiver um nome e mais nada, é bem adequado, é que eu acho que não será só isto.

Comment: @bigown Sim, por exemplo, quando a instância tem membros que referenciam objetos (espero que eu esteja certo sobre C#). MAs isso deve ocupar mais memória dependendo.

Comment: @Matheus não é bem isso não, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101 e tem o link na minha resposta acima. Estruturas ocupam menos memória se fizer certo, onde é certo