# Problema com matrizes

Tags: c#

Bem estou começando estudar a linguagem C#, tenho certa experiencia em Java, em java temos um certo problema em manipulação de matriz, pois, apesar de não existir ponteiro na linguagem propriamente dito, quando se trata de matrizes esse temo acaba existindo, pois ao copiar uma matriz A exemplo: ( matrizA = matrizB ). A matriz A acaba recendo o ponteiro da matrizB, desta forma tudo que se alterar na matirzA vai alterar na matrizB. Primeiro ponto queria saber esse problema também ocorre em C#. Fui realizar um teste, mas objetive um problema bem idiota logo de cara que não sei qual é o erro.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        int[,] jogo = new int[2, 2];
        jogo[0, 0] = 1;
        jogo[0, 1] = 2; 
        jogo[0, 2] = 3;
        jogo[1, 0] = 4;
        jogo[1, 1] = 5;
        jogo[1, 2] = 6;
        jogo[2, 0] = 7;
        jogo[2, 1] = 8;
        jogo[2, 2] = 9;

        int[,] teste = new int[2, 2];

        jogo = teste;

        Console.WriteLine(teste[0,0]+"|"+ teste[0, 1]+"|"+ teste[0, 2]);
        Console.WriteLine(teste[1, 0] + "|" + teste[1, 1] + "|" + teste[1, 2]);
        Console.WriteLine(teste[2, 0] + "|" + teste[2, 1] + "|" + teste[2, 2]);

    }
```

Por algum motivo está dando este erro : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz.' e não faço ideia do que eu tenha feito errado.

Comment: O erro acontece porque jogo[0,2] não existe porque são duas posições e o indice no C# começa do 0 então vai até 1 entendeu!

Comment: você criou a matriz de tamano 2, e tentou colocar 3 números dentro dela, nas posições `0`, `1` e `2`.... só pode `0` e `1`

Comment: assim fica certo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YXJ7zJ . E, o fato de alterar em uma, tambem alterar na outra, não é um problema, é uma característica porque o valor é passado por referência.

Comment: Também pode pensar assim, se você colocou 9 valores então é uma matriz `3x3` e não `2x2` porque `3x3=9`

Answer (score 2):

Como eu disse no comentário, não existe a posição referente 2 (`new int[0,2]`) porque o `C#` começa o seu índice do ***0*** e no caso do seu `array` criado vai até o ***1***.

Código correto mediante a instância `new int[2,2]`:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[,] jogo = new int[2, 2];
    jogo[0, 0] = 1;
    jogo[0, 1] = 2;     
    jogo[1, 0] = 4;
    jogo[1, 1] = 5;
}
```

Quanto a copia dos dados da maneira como você fez (`jogo = teste;`) é copiado por referencia, mas, poderia utilizar o `Array.Copy` para copiar somente os valores das posições da seguinte forma:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[,] jogo = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] teste = new int[2, 2];
    jogo[0, 0] = 1;
    jogo[0, 1] = 2;
    jogo[1, 0] = 3;
    jogo[1, 1] = 4;

    Array.Copy(jogo, teste, 4);
}
```

a partir dai qualquer alteração feita só acontece no `array` que foi destinado.

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Array.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Array.Copy Method (Array, Array, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx)

<sub>***Leitura***</sub>

- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mem%C3%B3ria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-refer%C3%AAncia)
- [Criar objetos sem referência C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212675/criar-objetos-sem-refer%C3%AAncia-c)